# does not contain a Gradle build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

'C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\StolenCarsReporting' does not contain a Gradle build.

I am getting this error Please help! I am new to android?

I tried closing/reopening project, importing project instead of opening, but did not worked!

Please guide me I am pretty new to android.

Comment: Is there a `build.gradle(.kts)` file in the target folder?